# Usar nomes de cores, RGB ou hexa?

Tags: css

Nesta **[documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)** encontro uma lista enorme de **nomes de cores** que podem ser usadas no CSS com seus respectivos valores em hexadecimal. Por exemplo:

```
--------------------------------------
| nome em En | nome em Pt |   hexa   |
--------------------------------------
| black      | preto      | #000000  |
--------------------------------------
| silver     | prata      | #c0c0c0  |
--------------------------------------
| white      | branco     | #ffffff  |
--------------------------------------
| red        | vermelho   | #ff0000  |
--------------------------------------
```

Para aplicar um fundo vermelho (`red`) a uma `div` eu poderia usar:

```
usando o nome da cor:             usando valor hexadecimal:

div{                              div{
   background-color: red;   OU       background-color: #ff0000;
}                                 }
```

Ou usando RGB:

```
div{
   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Pessoalmente acho muito mais prático usar `red` do que `#ff0000`, e aparentemente nunca me deparei com problemas em usar os nomes, mas não tenho 100% de certeza se isso é uma boa prática ou haja algum problema entre navegadores.

Minha dúvida é se posso usar **apenas os nomes das cores** em vez do valor hexadecimal ou RGB, e se isso implica em algum tipo de incompatibilidade entre navegadores. Qual seria o mais recomendado usar e porquê?

Comment: Até tempos atrás não era recomendado utilizar o nome da cor, pois suas componentes poderiam variar de navegador para navegador, podendo variar a exibição da aplicação; hoje acredito que isso não seja mais um problema.

Comment: Cara segundo a W3C não há problemas em chamar as cores pelos nomes... Inclusive lá tem uma tabela comparando nomeXhexa e não há diferença. Inclusive os nomes de cores também são válidos para o SVG

Comment: Não há nenhuma incompatibilidade entre usar nomes de cores, hexadecimal e RGB. Mas, se deseja obter uma cor com precisão de um tom específico que esteja querendo, pode-se usar hexadecimal ou rgb, mas a não ser isso, não tem nenhum problema.

Comment: Depende de quem for dar manutenção no CSS? Eu creio que se fosse escrever alguma resposta, iria nesse sentido. Irei pesquisar sobre o assunto, de toda sorte

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vou deixar alguns pontos a favor das duas:

**1. Facilidade de manutenção e modificações durante o desenvolvimento:**

Mudar o tom de uma cor para mais escuro ou mais claro ou até mesmo aplicar uma opacidade é mais simples com hex e rgb, basta aumentar ou diminuir os valores e adicionar o alpha:

Talvez `background-color: #ff0000;` não é bem o que queria, talvez um vermelho mais escuro com uma pequena opacidade, basta usar `rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.7)` ou `#99000099` (RGBA hexadecimal notation (#RRGGBBAA, #RGBA) não é suportado em todos navegadores)

**2. Mais simples de gravar**

Se você quer usar apenas nomes das cores, precisará consultar o tempo todo outro lugar pra saber qual é nome daquela cor, ou então gravar o nome de várias cores

Usando RGB ou HEX basta entender que as cores são formadas por três partes (4 se usar opacidade):

```
#001122                        rgb(0, 1, 2)
00 -> vermelho      OU         0 -> vermelho
11 -> verde                    1 -> verde
22 -> azul                     2 -> azul
```

Sabendo isso é só misturar

**3. "Essa é A cor"**

Talvez você esteja navegando na internet e de repente olha um site, anúncio ou algo assim e "essa é A cor" que você tava buscando pro seu site, o que você faz? pelo menos o que eu faço, inspeciono o elemento e vejo a cor usada, se for uma imagem, o chromer permite que passando o mouse por cima ele te diz qual é aquela cor em HEX, RGBA e HSLA, porém não diz o nome da cor, para isso seria um passo a mais, procurar algum conversor e ver qual o nome da cor

Mas claro, usar os nomes, tem suas vantagens:

**1. É mais intuitivo, pelo menos pra mim**

Se você está fazendo uma alteração simples e rápida provavelmente a primeira coisa que pense quando for colocar um fundo cinza é `gray` e não `#808080` ou `rgb(128, 128, 128)`

**2. Ajuda no inglês**

Se você quer aprender, aperfeiçoar ou até mesmo estudar pra prova, usar os nomes das cores já ajuda

Obs: é possível usar opacidade com nome de cores porém é necessário usar mais um atributo (`opacity`), mas, na minha opinião, com GRB ou HEX é bem mais fácil, já que a opacidade aplicada pelo `opacity` é em tudo, cores de fundo, do texto, borda ..., se quiser apenas aplicar a um desses vai dar trabalho

Answer (score 5):

A maior diferença é no teu poder de definição das cores, utilizando HEX você [consegue definir muito mais precisamente a cor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059228/css-hsl-or-rgba-colors) que deseja do que utilizando RGB e o nome literal. Além disso mesmo com os navegadores buscando uma padronização pode ocorrer de, para uma mesma cor definida com o nome literal, dois navegadores apresentarem leves diferenças.

Um ponto interessante é que utilizar [HEX faz a página renderizar um pouco mais rápido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620719/efficiency-of-color-selection-in-html-rgb-vs-hex-vs-name), a diferença é "mais notavél" se você adicionar RGBA na lista.

---

Fora os links adicionados acima estes posts podem complementar a leitura:

https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-to-use-HEX-or-RGB-color-property-in-CSS-to-make-less-server-source-consumption-and-make-the-CSS-load-faster

https://www.quora.com/How-many-colors-does-the-RGB-and-HEX-format-have-Which-is-better-for-screen-colors

Comment: O RGB tem a mesma precisão do HEX, não? A [questão linkada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059228/css-hsl-or-rgba-colors) faz contraponto do HSL com o RGB, que são esquemas de cor distintos. O HEX é diretamente derivável no RGB, um para um

Comment: Existem [falhas metodológicas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620719/efficiency-of-color-selection-in-html-rgb-vs-hex-vs-name/27531794#comment76983629_27531794) sobre o segundo link, da velocidade de renderização, então a conclusão não é sólida

Comment: 16 elevado a 6 ou 256 elevado a 3 = 16,777,216 de cores, ou seja os dois têm a mesma quantidade de cores, com a vantagem do RGB ter 3 dígitos por cor e pode te gerar uma cor muito mais precisa além do canal alpha RGBA que vc pode usar. Esse canal Alpha por sua vez pode diminuir a performance da renderização da página. E a pergunta é sobre o nome da cor, não RGB vs HEX...

Comment: Outra coisa. Se forem milhões de ocorrências o HEX leva vantagem apenas por justamente ter menos dígitos, #ffffff vs rgb(255,255,255)

Answer (score 3):

### [Nomes no padrão SVG 1.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Color_keywords)

Eu acredito que a resposta esteja na própria documentação que você colocou como referência na pergunta. Eu coloquei no título o link para a página em português para a parte que fala sobre o uso dos nomes das cores, que me parece ser a sua principal dúvida.

Em resumo, você pode usar os nomes com alguns cuidados.

- Usar os [nomes definidos no padrão SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords) (CSS 3)
- [Se rodar em IE < 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Compatibilidade_do_navegador) cuidar com os nomes: `grey`, `darkgrey`, `darkslategrey`, `dimgrey`, `lightgrey` e `lightslategrey` pois são aceitos or terminados em "gray" e não em "grey" nessas versões.
- Lembrar que alguns nomes são sinônimos para uma mesma cor
- Cores nomeadas não te darão recurso de transparência
- Não use os [nomes de cores relacionados ao S.O.](http://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#System_Colors) porque foram descontinuados

Por isso não vejo problema em utilizar os nomes das cores, porém como colocou o Guilherme, na [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308816/43) você tem as vantagens e desvantagens de usar apenas os nomes.

Se for uma questão de padronização, pode ser uma boa ideia porque você restringe a paleta e não erra em tonalidades diferentes, por outro lado, dependendo do projeto você pode precisar de uma gama maior de tonalidades e cores e apenas com os nomes não vai alcançar seu objetivo.

Answer (score 3):

Voce pode especificar cores com pelo menos **10 formas diferentes** de acordo com o último draft do [CSS Color Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/).

Este é um teste que mostra essas formas:

```css
.colorName{
   color: red
}

.colorRGB{
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0)
}

.colorRGBA{
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0, 50%)
}

.colorRGBP{
  color: rgb(100% 0% 0%)
}

.colorHSL{
  color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%)
}

.colorHSLA{
  color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%, 50%)
}

.colorHWB{
  color: hwb(0  0%  0%)
}

.colorGray{
  color: gray(50)
}

.colorCMYK{
  color: device-cmyk(0 100% 100% 50%);
}

.colorHex{
   color: #ff0000
 }
```

```html
<h2 class="colorName">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorRGB">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorRGBA">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorRGBP">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorHSL">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorHSLA">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorHWB">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorGray">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorCMYK">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
<h2 class="colorHex">O rato roeu a rolha da garrafa do rei da russia</h2>
```

O suporte para algumas dessas formas (por exemplo hwb) pode ser práticamente inexistente. O que vi até agora é existem bibliotecas javascript para proporcionar o devido suport. Como pode ver no [exemplo do W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hwb.asp)

Voce pode até consultar o suporte desta especificacao no seu browser. A especificacao inclui um [conjunto de testes](http://test.csswg.org/suites/css-color-4_dev/nightly-unstable/) que lhe permite verificar o suporte para o seu browser.

---

Mas respondendo mais especificamente á sua pergunta voce deve usar aquele que voce quiser. Eventualmente a sua escolha poderá estar relacionada ao esquema de cores que voce está habituado ou aquele que se adequa melhor ás circunstancias.

Se voce estiver habituado a um esquema de cores aditivo (RGB) entao voce usará RGB. Se voce estiver habituado a esquema de cores subtractivo (CMYK) entao voce usará CMYK.

Se voce for designer e trabalhar muito com o esquema de cores HSL entao voce puderá usar HSL.

O fato do esquema RGB ser bastante usado no mundo de informática é porque as telas tem fundo preto, entao um esquema aditivo de cores, como o RGB, funciona melhor que um esquema subtractivo. Voce pode ver o esquema subtrativo de cores em funcionamento em impressoras, uma vez que elas imprimem em papel branco.<sup>[ref](http://www.amopintar.com/modelos-de-cor/)</sup>

Contundo acho que pode ser feito uma ressalva, mas é algo subtil e opcional.
Voce pode querer associar uma determinada cor a um estado comum na sua aplicacao web. Por exemplo: vermelho para erro, amarelo para aviso, azul para informacao.

E os seres humanos estao mais habituados a reconhecerem nomes do que numeros (é por isso que existem DNS - mas isso é outro assunto). De forma a que nestas ocasioes voce poderá querer preferir o nome da cor em relacao a qulaquer outra alternativa.